# 'com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory' is deprecated. What are my options?

Tags: java, jackson, gmail, gmail-api, jackson2

While following the [Gmail API java quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)  I came across this code snippet:

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

Using it in the editor gave me a warning that it is deprecated. What are my options?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look up the [API documentation of class `JacksonFactory`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/json/jackson2/JacksonFactory.html).
It tells you what to do:

> **Deprecated.**
> use com.google.api.client.json.GsonFactory instead

Looking into the [API documentation of class `GsonFactory`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/json/gson/GsonFactory.html)
you see, its API methods are compatible to those of `JacksonFactory`,
since both extend from the same superclass `JsonFactory`.
(Only their internal implementations are different, of course.)

Therefore it is simple to change your code. Just to replace the line

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

by

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

Comment: Now it's not just deprecated. It's removed. Wonder which dependency used it :)

Answer (score 2):

The actual class is com.google.api.client.json.**gson.**GsonFactory.  The deprecation message is missing ".gson".